# Blackberry Twitter API ME integration prob

Tags: blackberry, twitter

I want to integrate Twitter in my Blackberry app. I am working on Blackberry JDE 5.0. I imported [Twitter_oath\lib\twitter_api_me-1.8.jar](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/1.8) creating a lib and make my project dependent on it. When I try to build the my app, it is successful. But when I try to run it in the simulator it gives error saying:

**Module 'Twitter_lib' has verification error 2618 at offset 2a28 (codfile version 78)**

'Twitter_lib' is the library I have created for importing jar file of Twitter API ME. My project is dependent on 'Twitter_lib'

What may be the problem and how to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: twitter api me 1.8 jar is works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [latest lib package from Project Kenai](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/1.8)
2. In **dist** folder of project you will find all needed jar files, copy them all into your project
   [image]
3. Add all jars to your project build path
   [image]

Should work, hope that helps!